# Visual Studio 2012 Group Solution need individual connection strings per developer

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, ef-code-first

We have a project that is being worked on currently by 5 developers and could get more at any time.  The developers are located at different places in the US.  Our back end is Code First Entity Framework based on a SQL Server database.

Some of the developers have SQL Server Express and some have full blown SQL Server.  We need a way to have the solution everyone works on but each developer needs to have his own connection string to the data so they can connect to their individual instances.  We cant use localhost because express versions have named instances of SQLEXPRESS.

We could just change the connection string when we grab the code form Git but then every time we sync we will have conflicts to merge so that would be a pain.

Has anyone run into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple solution would be to have everyone use SQL Server Express or SQL Server Developer Edition. You can install both side-by-side, so that should not be an issue. Especially since SQL Express is free...

Another option is to define a [SQL Server Connection Alias on each client with a predefined name](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/01/07/connection-alias.aspx). Then add the alias to your `.config`. That way the SQL Client will resolve to the right database and you can define one static value in your `.config`.

The 3rd solution is to [add a `configsource="connectionstrings.config"` and create these files on the local workspace, but don't check them in](http://www.mojoportal.com/using-separate-files-for-config-sections.aspx). You can add a `connectionstrings.template.config` and check that in to provide a starting point. These files don't need to be part of the solution.

The 4th option is to store the connectionstring in a `.Settings` file, set it to user and use the standard configuration API to store the connectionstring in the application settings folder of the users profile. You'll need to pass the connectionstring to the constructor of the Context class.

Comment: thanks for the help.  I think we are going to try a version of your 4th option